# Creating norm of an numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have this numpy array

```
X = [[ -9.03525007   7.45325017  33.34074879][ -6.63700008   5.13299996  31.66075039][ -5.12724996   8.25149989  30.92599964][ -5.12724996   8.25149989  30.92599964]]
```

I want to get the norm of this array using numpy. How can I do that?

for every array inside, I need sqrt(x2+y2+z2), so my output wull be array of 4 values (since there are 4 inside arrays)

Comment: Can you define "norm"?

Comment: it means for every array inside, I need sqrt(x2+y2+z2), so my output wull be array of 4 values (since there are 4 inside arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get what you ask for (the 2-norm of each row in your array), you can use the `axis` argument to `numpy.linalg.norm`:

```
import numpy
x = numpy.array([[ -9.03525007,   7.45325017,  33.34074879],
                 [ -6.63700008,   5.13299996,  31.66075039],
                 [ -5.12724996,   8.25149989,  30.92599964],
                 [ -5.12724996,   8.25149989,  30.92599964]])
print numpy.linalg.norm(x, axis=1)

=> 

array([ 35.33825423,  32.75363451,  32.41594355,  32.41594355])
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use `numpy.linalg.norm`

```
import numpy

x = [[ -9.03525007, 7.45325017 , 33.34074879], [ -6.63700008  , 5.13299996  , 31.66075039], [ -5.12724996 , 8.25149989 , 30.92599964], [ -5.12724996   , 8.25149989  , 30.92599964]]

print numpy.linalg.norm(x)
```

**Output:**

```
66.5069889437
```

Comment: thanks. but what if i need norm(2) which means for this input I i will get an array with 4 values. [norm(x), norm(y), norm(z)]

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean **matrix norm(s)**? If so:

```
import numpy as np
>>> xs = [[ -9.03525007, 7.45325017, 33.34074879], [-6.63700008, 5.13299996, 31.66075039], [-5.12724996, 8.25149989, 30.92599964], [-5.12724996, 8.25149989, 30.92599964]]
>>> np.linalg.norm(xs)
66.506988943656381
```

See: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html

Answer (score 0):

Other people have already given you the `norm()` function. You are probably looking to `map()` the `norm()` function within the array.

Just do:

```
from numpy.linalg import norm
norms = map(norm, x)
```